# Warning: GDAL Error '1' and Error: Node stack overflow

Tags: r, ggplot2, nodes, gdal, proj

*OS: Windows*

I am plotting a raster file after changing the CRS of the same with `st_transform`. Here, is a warning of GDAL Error 1 being generated.
Later, I changed the CRS of the vector/feature file with the newly transformed raster file.
While I am trying to plot *sf* data (point) with *ggplot* on R, it too is bouncing back the same error **GDAL Error 1**, indicating that I might be having multiple versions of PROJ lib which seems to be making the error.  The key thing that I noticed was the error message. It was showing the Postgresql directory while mentioning the error message. The error code is mentioned below:
**Error_1:**
`GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_identify: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.2\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 0 whereas a number >= 2 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.`

However, though the raster file was successfully plotted, the final error of node stack overflew `(Error: node stack overflow`)  was propagated while I was trying to plot the crs_transormed feature classes on the raster.

- PostGIS, R- I have these three applications installed, that use GDAL. I also use QGIS.
- The PROJ package's version which is installed on R is **0.4.0**.
- If GDAL failed when it successfully tried to transform the point feature's coordinates from the source raster file, it would provide an error message.
- I  was trying to use R to develop on VS  Code before this error landed. After I started to use R on VS, R Studio started to have this problem.
- I tried uninstalling and installing the rgdal but that did not help.

Though the raster file's CRS transformation was generating the warning messages of having multiple versions of PROJ, it plotted the raster file but the problem occurred when the feature points were to be plotted on the raster file.

1. Is it now needed to do a clean installation of GDAL? If yes, then how about doing it **without** uninstalling Postgis?
2. I already reinstalled R to circumvent the problem but that didn't help.

Any sort of assistance would help.

**Complete code:**

```
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(ggplot2)

options(expressions = 500000)

dsm_Hrvd <- read_stars("data/dd/ddd/dddd.tif")
dsm_Hrvd
harv_plot <- st_read("data//dd/ddd/dddd.shp")
harv_plot

st_crs(dsm_Hrvd)
st_crs(harv_plot)

target_crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
dsm_Hrvd_rprj <- st_transform(dsm_Hrvd, crs = target_crs)
# or dsm_Hrvd_rprj <- st_transform(dsm_Hrvd, 4326) in case the crs in't recognized
harv_plot_rprj <- st_transform(harv_plot, st_crs(dsm_Hrvd_rprj))

# warnings()

ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = dsm_Hrvd) +
  # scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  geom_sf(data = harv_plot_rprj, mapping = aes(color = plot_type))
```

*Additional Information*:

1. I also checked the GDAL Python version with OSGeoShell:

```
>>> from osgeo import osr
>>> osr.GetPROJVersionMajor()
9
>>> osr.GetPROJVersionMinor()
1
```

2. The error occurs both on R Studio & VS Code
3. Updated the R Studio to the **build 494, version 2023.09.1**

**(If any key information seems to be amiss, do notify. The same will be added)**

Comment: Are sf and/or stars packages built from source? Binary packages are built and delivered with GDAL and PROJ and should not care about other GDAL and PROJ versions you have on your system. Were library paths the same for RStudio and VS Code R sessions?  When you reinstalled R, did you also remove existing packages?

Comment: @margusl,
Q1- Yes, the packages were built from the source, both times.
Q2- It is so.
Q3- Yes, I did. I removed the folder of previously existing packages. 

If it takes, then I will do it again as long as I do not mess up the Postgres setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem. I've just updated my R and Rtools to the current versions (v4.3.1 and 43). My error is the same when trying to load a shapefile or specify a CRS. Pretty much when needing to do anything with the CRS component of GDAL being used...

```
shp <- read_sf("./states.shp")
Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_identify: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\share\contrib\postgis-3.2\proj\proj.db contains DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR = 0 whereas a number >= 2 is expected. It comes from another PROJ installation.
```

UPDATE: This has now been solved by following the instructions here: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2248

In short, I needed to create a new path for PROJ_LIB in the PC's environmental variables that was linked to the R `sf` packages' proj folder.